# Repeated Animated Custom Control while scrolling listview in android

Tags: android, listview, scroll, scrollview

I have a custom control in a listview to showing playing progress when I click in a listitem.

When I click in a listitem and when it's playing the sound I show a progress circle but if I scroll the listview this custom control it's showing each 6 rows above.

**This is my problem:**
http://i43.tinypic.com/34dsx2e.png

This is the getView of my CustomAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
         mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
         holder = new ViewHolder(convertView); 
         convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.position = position;


    Item item = getItem(position);
    holder.progressWheel.setPosition(position);
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(item.getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The progress circle appears because you are recycling the convertView (the listview sends you on the convertView param a previously used view to reduce memory usage). There are two solutions:

A) Do not recycle the convertView (sub-obtimal)

Replace:

```
if (convertView == null) {
     mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
     convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
     holder = new ViewHolder(convertView); 
     convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

with:

```
 mInflater = (LayoutInflater)  mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);          
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
 holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
```

B) Hide the progressWheel on the view before "return convertview"